# Проблема с функцией onclick

Tags: javascript

```js
btn.onclick = function() {
  if (man.value = 'man') {
    document.getElementsByClassName('circle')[0].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  } else if (woman.value = 'woman') {
    document.getElementsByClassName('circle')[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="f2">
  <input type="radio" id="man" name="radio" value="man">
  <p class="offset">man</p>
  <input type="radio" id="woman" name="radio" value="woman">
  <p>woman</p>
</form>
```

Вобщем, при клике на

```js
btn.onclick = function() {
  if (man.value = 'man') {
    document.getElementsByClassName('circle')[0].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  } else if (woman.value = 'woman') {
    document.getElementsByClassName('circle')[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  right: 40%;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<form name="f2">
  <input type="radio" id="man" name="radio" value="man">
  <p class="offset">man</p>
  <input type="radio" id="woman" name="radio" value="woman">
  <p>woman</p>
</form>

<div class="circle"></div>
```

В общем, помогите разобраться, так как я новичок в JS и не очень понимаю в чем проблема: При клике на man, затем на кнопку,  circle должен менять цвет на синий. Если  на woman, то на красный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector(".circle").onclick = function() {
  if (man.checked) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('circle')[0].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  } else if (woman.checked) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('circle')[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  right: 40%;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<form name="f2">
  <input type="radio" id="man" name="radio" value="man">
  <p class="offset">man</p>
  <input type="radio" id="woman" name="radio" value="woman">
  <p>woman</p>
</form>

<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: я так понимаю, здесь не нужно плюсовать, так не получен ещё знак за принятые ответы с нулем голосов? :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/51/unsung-hero